# .net file.create causes access denied

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing locally web application. I am trying to upload file and I have the following code:

```
  foreach (var file in provider.Contents)
  {
      var mappedPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Resources/TmpUploadedFiles");                    
      var dataStream = await file.ReadAsStreamAsync();
      FileStream fileStream = File.Create(mappedPath, (int)dataStream.Length);
   }
```

This method is inside `WebApi controller`.

As a result I get {"Access to the path '...\Resources\TmpUploadedFiles' is denied."}

The folder "Resources/TmpUploadedFiles" is inside webproject. What makes it "denied"? Where to set access rights? This is local machine.

Comment: Does the user under which your app is running have write permission to that folder?